# extracting values from a Dataframe rows using non unique values in other rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

Given the following Dataframe,

```
  SecondsInDay  Min  Max
0             0    1    2
1           300    3    4
2           600    5    6
3             0    7    8
4           300    1    0
5           300    2   12
6           300    4   56
```

I want to extract overall minimum and maximum value for every row where SecondsInDay = 300.

Being new to DataFrames, it took a while but I wrote the following code:

```
val = df[df.SecondsInDay==300]
index=val.index
maxVal=val['Max'][index[0]]
minVal=val['Min'][index[0]]
for d in index:
    if maxVal < val['Max'][d]:
        maxVal = val['Max'][d]
    if minVal> val['Min'][d]:
        minVal= val['Min'][d]
```

which indeed returns the correct values

```
maxVal=56
minVal=1
```

However, I read that iterating through DataFrames is not good particularly at scale,

therefore could I have written this better?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we can do `agg`

```
df.loc[df.SecondsInDay==300].agg({'Min':'min','Max':'max'})
Out[122]: 
Min     1
Max    56
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

IICU

```
df[df['SecondsInDay']==300].agg(['max','min'] )
```

[image]

Comment: This only works because the max and min are in this case both in correct columns.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Erfan. Will leave it there just in case, someone else may benefit from your comments.